# use build parameter in batch call in jenkins Freestyle job

Tags: batch-file, jenkins

I want to execute a robocopy action inside my Freestyle Jobs build section. But I dont know how to use my predefined Text Parameters. Neither **${PARAM}** nor **env.PARAM** are working. Inside other calls like *Artifact Deployment* everything works fine with **${PARAM}**. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using %PARAM% ?

Comment: Yes. Didnt work either. `Script1.groovy: 3: unexpected token: % @ line 3, column 18.
   copyBatString << %TESTPARAM% << 'TESTPARAM'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point I think it is not possible to use them directly in the `bat '...'` command. But you can use the variables and a `Stringbuilder` to define your string which can be executed with the `bat` command.